# installing portia successful in windows but failed to run

Tags: scrapy, portia

My computer is Win7 64 and I have install vagrant and virtualbox.
I have  installed portia through follow way:

```
git clone https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia
vagrant up
```

The result in the cmd can be showed in this:

```
==> default: Installing collected packages: slybot
==> default:   Running setup.py develop for slybot
==> default:
==> default:     warning: no files found matching 'slybot/splash-script-combined
.js'
==> default:     Creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/slybot.egg-link
 (link to .)
==> default:     Adding slybot 0.13.0b32 to easy-install.pth file
==> default:     Installing slybot script to /usr/local/bin
==> default:     Installing portiacrawl script to /usr/local/bin
==> default:
==> default:     Installed /vagrant/slybot
==> default: Successfully installed slybot
==> default: Cleaning up...
==> default: Executing command: configure_nginx
==> default: Executing command: configure_initctl
==> default: Starting slyd service
==> default: =====================
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong
```

.

Given to this result,I think I have successful install portia.
But when I open `http://localhost:9001`  or `http://127.0.0.1:9001` in my chrome browser, there is nothing happened.

And when I open '`http://127.0.0.1:2222`', I can find:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
Protocol mismatch.
```

And when I open '`http://33.33.33.10`', I can find:

```
Welcome to nginx!  
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.  
For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.  
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.  
Thank you for using nginx.
```

I also try it again in my Win7_Child_VHD system,but the results is the same.
I also  try to  install portia in the docker, but it is also failed and I am not remembering the result.
I have also  try to install portia in my vmware of ubuntu:14.04  ,but it is too complicated for me and I have to give up.

It has puzzled me for almost three weeks, and I have to give up if i couldn't solve the problem.

I know i can run portia in [scrapinghub/portia](https://scrapinghub.com/portia). 
But I really want to know how to run portia locally. So i want to know how to resolve the problems.